# flutter_facebook_login plugin issues logging in on iOS simulator (using Android Studio)

Tags: ios, firebase, android-studio, flutter, facebook-login

I'm building a Flutter app with Android Studio (a Time Tracker, following a course on Udemy) and I am at the stage where I have created a sign-in page, that allows me to sign in using either Google, Facebook, email or 'going anonymous'. I'm using version 2.0.1 of the flutter_facebook_login plugin, since the latest version, version 3.0.0, generates lots of errors related to Cocoapods. Version 2.0.1 resolves all of those errors.

I'm doing all authentication using Flutter's firebase_auth package, so that a unique user ID can be generated, to control what is seen by each user. The sign-in process is split into two different pages. There's an 'auth.dart' page that handles all of the authorisation work, with Firebase, Google and Facebook etc. It looks like this:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_facebook_login/flutter_facebook_login.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';

class User {
  User({@required this.uid});
  final String uid;
}

abstract class AuthBase {
  Stream<User> get onAuthStateChanged;
  Future<User> currentUser();
  Future<User> signInAnonymously();
  Future<User> signInWithGoogle();
  Future<User> signInWithFacebook();
  Future<void> signOut();
}

class Auth implements AuthBase {
  final _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  User _userFromFirebase(FirebaseUser user) {
    if (user == null) {
      return null;
    }
    return User(uid: user.uid);
  }

  @override
  Stream<User> get onAuthStateChanged {
    return _firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged.map(_userFromFirebase);
  }

  @override
  Future<User> currentUser() async {
    final user = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser();
    return _userFromFirebase(user);
  }

  @override
  Future<User> signInAnonymously() async {
    final authResult = await _firebaseAuth.signInAnonymously();
    return _userFromFirebase(authResult.user);
  }

  @override
  Future<User> signInWithGoogle() async {
    final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
    final googleAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    if (googleAccount != null) {
      final googleAuth = await googleAccount.authentication;
      if (googleAuth.accessToken != null && googleAuth.idToken != null) {
        final authResult = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(
          GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
            idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
            accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
          ),
        );
        return _userFromFirebase(authResult.user);
      } else {
        throw PlatformException(
          code: 'ERROR_MISSING_GOOGLE_AUTH_TOKEN',
          message: 'Missing Google Auth Token',
        );
      }
    } else {
      throw PlatformException(
        code: 'ERROR_ABORTED_BY_USER',
        message: 'Sign in aborted by user',
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<User> signInWithFacebook() async {
    final facebookLogin = FacebookLogin();
    final result = await facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(
      ['public_profile'],
    );
    if (result.accessToken != null) {
      final authResult = await _firebaseAuth
          .signInWithCredential(FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(
        accessToken: result.accessToken.token,
      ));
      return _userFromFirebase(authResult.user);
    } else {
      throw PlatformException(
        code: 'ERROR_ABORTED_BY_USER',
        message: 'Sign in aborted by user',
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<void> signOut() async {
    final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
    await googleSignIn.signOut();
    final facebookLogin = FacebookLogin();
    await facebookLogin.logOut();
    await _firebaseAuth.signOut();
  }
}
```

Then, the sign-in page, with all of the buttons and interactions with Google and Facebook etc. looks like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:time_tracker_flutter_course/app/sign_in/sign_in_button.dart';
import 'package:time_tracker_flutter_course/app/sign_in/social_sign_in_button.dart';
import 'package:time_tracker_flutter_course/services/auth.dart';

class SignInPage extends StatelessWidget {
  SignInPage({@required this.auth});
  final AuthBase auth;

  Future<void> _signInAnonymously() async {
    try {
      await auth.signInAnonymously();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }

  Future<void> _signInWithGoogle() async {
    try {
      await auth.signInWithGoogle();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }

  Future<void> _signInWithFacebook() async {
    try {
      await auth.signInWithFacebook();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Time Tracker'),
        elevation: 2.0,
      ),
      body: _buildContent(),
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildContent() {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'Sign In',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 32.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 48.0),
          SocialSignInButton(
            assetName: 'images/google-logo.png',
            text: 'Sign in with Google',
            textColor: Colors.black87,
            color: Colors.white,
            onPressed: _signInWithGoogle,
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 8.0),
          SocialSignInButton(
            assetName: 'images/facebook-logo.png',
            text: 'Sign in with Facebook',
            textColor: Colors.white,
            color: Color(0xFF334D92),
            onPressed: _signInWithFacebook,
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 8.0),
          SignInButton(
            text: 'Sign in with email',
            textColor: Colors.white,
            color: Colors.teal[700],
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 8.0),
          Text(
            'or',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0, color: Colors.black87),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 8.0),
          SignInButton(
            text: 'Go anonymous',
            textColor: Colors.black,
            color: Colors.lime[300],
            onPressed: _signInAnonymously,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

All this code and methodology works perfectly in most cases, which includes:

- Android simulator with anonymous login, Google AND Facebook
- iOS simulator with anonymous login and Google ONLY

When I try and log in with the Facebook method on the iOS simulator in Android Studio, that's where I run into problems. In the Android Studio console, an error is 'spat out':

```
flutter: PlatformException(ERROR_ABORTED_BY_USER, Sign in aborted by user, null)
```

You'll see from the first block of code (the 'auth.dart' code) that this error is just a generic one that I have built in - I haven't been specific with it at all.

I don't believe the issue is with the flutter_facebook_login plugin, since it still works for Android, unless the plug-in has problems that are unique to iOS. I think there's an issue with the iOS set-up for Facebook, even though I have followed the instructions to the letter, including with Xcode.

Can someone help me to understand what might be causing this error, and how I can sort it? It is the only thing in the set-up that you can see that isn't working at the moment, across both simulator platforms.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, I think it is an issue of facebook api with ios beta version.
I found a work around. This is only a work around not the actual solution. It works for me and I hope this helps you:-

The work around checking when the status goes to FacebookLoginStatus.cancelledByUser, then using the below

```
 facebookLogin.loginBehavior = FacebookLoginBehavior.webViewOnly;
```

It will force flutter to open facebook auth in webview and then you can get it working.

Have a look at the full method

```
 Future signInWithFaceBook() async{
   var facebookLogin = new FacebookLogin();
   var result = await facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(['email', 'public_profile']);
   switch (result.status) {
     case FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn:
       print(result.accessToken.token);
       // Add your route to home page here after sign In
       break;
     case FacebookLoginStatus.cancelledByUser:
    // In your case the program flow will go here as it as a bug with the api I suppose

       facebookLogin.loginBehavior = FacebookLoginBehavior.webViewOnly;
// Once the code comes here the above line will force flutter to open facebook auth in a webview
       result = await facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(['email', 'public_profile']);

       if(result.status==FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn){
         FirebaseUser user = (await _auth.signInWithCredential(FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(accessToken: result.accessToken.token)
         )
         ).user;
         final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
         assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);
         // Add your home page here
       }
       print('CANCELED BY USER');
       break;
     case FacebookLoginStatus.error:
       print(result.errorMessage);
       break;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the feedback! I've created a separate flutter project, to work on your suggestion and to see if I can get it to work. In my main one, I have just removed the Facebook functionality, to be sure it works right now, if that makes sense...

Answer (score 0):

Update your auth.dart Code with one line of code from the below .It works.

```
@override

Future <User> signInWithFacebook() async {

final facebookLogin = FacebookLogin();
facebookLogin.LoginBehavior = FacebookLoginBehavior.webViewOnly;
final result = await facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile'],); 

if (result.accessToken != null) {
  final authResult = await _firebaseAuth
      .signInWithCredential(FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(
    accessToken: result.accessToken.token,
  )
);
  return _userFromFirebase(authResult.user);
} else {
  throw PlatformException(
    code: 'ERROR_ABORTED_BY_USER',
    message: 'Sign in aborted by user',
  );
}}
```

Comment: Hi there, please quote the relevant code directly in your answer instead of linking to an image of code.